# Why electric field symmetry along $z$-axis implies vanishing of odds multipole moments

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

In the Jackson exercise 6.4, we have the following electric field inside a rotating sphere,

$$
  \vec{E} = -\frac{2}{3} \mu_0 M \omega r \hat{r}
$$

Where $r$ is the radial coordinate in cylindrical coordinate $(r, \theta, z)$.

We recall the multipole expansion,
$$
q_{lm} = \int d^3x' \rho(x')r'^{l}Y^{\ast}_{lm}(\theta', \phi')
$$

Then, since $E \sim r$, we have the following symmetry of the inner electric field,
$$
 \vec{E}(x,y,z) = \vec{E}(x,y,-z)
$$

Which implies that the *odds moments of the multipole expansion* vanish : $q_{(2k+1),m} = 0$.

I do not understand why such a symmetry implies that ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Additional_properties_of_Legendre_polynomials

Comment: You are using $\rho$ to mean both charge density and cylindrical radial coordinate.